# Install application wrapper script wrap.sh

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk, android-package-managers

Android offers a really powerful way to control application process start - it is so called [wrapper script](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#3793). It is a simple shell script named `wrap.sh` that should be placed in the app installation `lib/` directory (one that contains native libraries, if any):

```
#!/system/bin/sh
my_wrapper_cmd $@
```

If an app has such script the system won't fork zygote to create hosting process for the application. Instead once user tries to launch app - system invokes that script to [start](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Process.java#406) brand new `app_process` with separate JVM. It is extremely useful if you e.g. want to launch app under Valgrind or do some `LD_PRELOAD`. (It works only for debuggable APKs, but it doesn't matter for now)

At the moment I'm able to create an APK that contains `libs/<my_device_abi>/wrap.sh`. Thanks to this [snippet](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/simpleperf/demo/SimpleperfExamplePureJava/app/profiling.gradle#19). But after installation I see no `wrap.sh` in device's `lib/` folder:

```
sailfish:/ $ run-as com.example.sergik.ndksample                             
sailfish:/data/data/com.example.sergik.ndksample $ ls -l lib/
total 40
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system 13832 1979-11-30 00:00 libnative-lib.so
```

There are only packaged `.so` libraries. At the same time APK contains that script. So obviously package manager has skipped it.

And the question: does anyone know how to put my script to device or force package manager to respect it?

P.S. Device is not rooted, and trying to push `wrap.sh` via `run-as` won't work since `lib/` is owned by the system and application has no priviledges to write some stuff there.