# How to package "wrap.sh" shell script with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, address-sanitizer

I am trying to launch my application through a wrap.sh script as in [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/wrap-script.html#creating_the_wrap_shell_script), but When putting my wrap.sh in the right place, it is not bundled in my apk.

Here is the relevant build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    sourceSets.main {
        res.srcDirs "res"
        assets.srcDirs '../../Resources/data/app', '../../Resources/data/content'
        jniLibs.srcDirs "jni"
        java.srcDirs "javasrc"
        manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
    }
    buildTypes {
        sanitize_debug {
            initWith buildTypes.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false

            sourceSets.main {
                jniLibs.srcDirs +=  "jni/sanitizer/libs"
            }

[...]

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'generateSanitize_debugBuildConfig') {
        task.dependsOn createWrapScriptAddDir
    }
}

static def writeWrapScriptToFullyCompileJavaApp(wrapFile, abi) {
    if(abi == "armeabi" || abi == "armeabi-v7a")
        abi = "arm"
    if(abi == "arm64-v8a")
        abi = "aarch64"
    if (abi == "x86")
        abi = "i686"
    wrapFile.withWriter { writer ->
        writer.write('#!/system/bin/sh\n')
        writer.write('HERE="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"\n')
        writer.write('export ASAN_OPTIONS=log_to_syslog=false,allow_user_segv_handler=1,detect_container_overflow=0\n')
        //writer.write('export ASAN_ACTIVATION_OPTIONS=include_if_exists=/data/local/tmp/asan.options.b\n')
        writer.write("export LD_PRELOAD=\$HERE/libclang_rt.asan-${abi}-android.so\n")
        writer.write('\$@\n')
    }
}

task createWrapScriptAddDir(dependsOn: copyASANLibs) {
    for (String abi : rootProject.ext.abiFilters) {
        def dir = new File("jni/sanitizer/libs/" + abi)
        dir.mkdirs()
        def wrapFile = new File(dir, "wrap.sh")
        writeWrapScriptToFullyCompileJavaApp(wrapFile, abi)
        println "write file " + wrapFile.path
    }
}
```

and my resulting lib folder in my apk only contains my so files (which are correctly copied from their respective "jni/sanitizer/libs/abi" folder to the lib folder in the apk) and not my wrap.sh file.

I do actually see my wrap.sh file in my android studio folder view (and on my disk), but there is none in the apk.

(I am trying to build in android studio my so file with sanitizer as in [here](https://virtualrealitypop.com/oreo-ndk-secrets-7d075a9b084))

Comment: Seems like no one found a solution in 7 months: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935575/install-application-wrapper-script-wrap-sh

Comment: I have the same issue, can't seem to get the `wrap.sh` to be included in the APK. Have you had any luck in finding a solution?

Comment: Unfortunatly not yet. I am going to try to use sanitizer again in a few weeks. I might find a solution then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a solution (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870291/android-studio-address-sanitizer-using-build-gradle/49983260#49983260)). The workaround is to put the script in a "resources/targetArchitecture" folder, which you can then bundle in the apk.